# Objective-c get position of an iboutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

When I try

```
myLabel.frame.origin.x
```

It's returning 0.000000.
How can I get exact position of any iboutlet?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking how to get an absolute position as compared to a relative one (frame is relative to superview).

Answer (score 2):

A view's frame is relative to its parent view (superview). To get the frame relative to the screen, you do:

```
CGRect screenRect = [myLabel convertRect:self.bounds toView:nil];
```

To get the frame relative to some other view, replace `nil` with the other view.

Comment: @ItayAmza I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I was answering Edwin Iskandar's question. anyway my question is how can I get the absolute position.

Comment: To answer Edwin's question, post your comment to his question. Doesn't my answer give you what you want? If not, please define what you mean by "absolute position".

Comment: I want to position a UIBottunTypeContactAdd next to a lable on my view, so in viewDidLoad I need the position of the lable so I can make the label and the button parallel

Comment: Assuming the label and button have the same superview, simply get the label's `frame`. Use the frame's values to set the frame of the button.

Comment: That's what I did, but frame origin values returning 0.00000

Comment: Either the frame's origin really is 0 or your variable is `nil`. Check to see if `myLabel` is `nil` or not.

Comment: According to my storyboard the origin is (20,98). I changed the label text from inside the class so it cant be nil, what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing this? The view controller's view must be loaded before the outlets are connected. A safe place is in awakeFromNib.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that...

1. You are calling this after the NIB has been loaded (viewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, viewDidX)
2. You have hooked up the view to the NIB in interface builder.

See this guide on the iOS Developer Library for detail on making the connection from a view in your NIB to an IBOutlet...
[Configuring the View Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html)

Comment: My problem is that I want to position a UIBottunTypeContactAdd next to a lable, so I calling this in the viewDidLoad method